# How to use inidicator constraints with multiple boolean conditions - Gurobi

Tags: linear-programming, gurobi, mixed-integer-programming

I regularly use indicator constraints, is there an easy way to write (e.g.) : if `z1` and `z2` (boolean) are both true then a particular constraint holds. So essentially use indicator constraints with a series of boolean logic

Comment: If you can assume, that there is a binary-indicator variable available for each of your elements to reason about: just treat it as boolean algebra: (minimize), convert to CNF, CNF -> MILP is trivial then (series of `a*x.T >= 1` constraints). `Hooker, John N. Integrated methods for optimization. Vol. 170. New York: Springer, 2012.` would have some more advanced treatment in general (but also using CNFs) if i remember correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directly, am not sure you can do, however, if you want to express:

```
z1 == 1 AND z2 == 1 ==> constraint_holds
```

introduce another auxiliary binary variable `z3`, and state the following constraint:

```
z3 == AND(z1, z2)
```

and then you can use `z3` as:

```
z3 == 1 ==> constraint_holds
```